# How can I send messages from bot in specific group topic

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm searching a way to automatically send messages from a bot in a specific group's topic.
To better explain:
I created a bot and a group (named i.ex. Home) and added the bot in the group. Got the group chat id.
A quick test, sending a message in this group, was successful.
Now I'd like to create topics in this group, i.ex. Temperature, Network and so on.

What I'd like to accomplish is that various services in my home could post messages in the right topic. Home assistant temperature sensors in the Home/Temperature topic, network checks in the Home/Network and so on.

Thank you very much

Elvis D.

Comment: I also have the same problem in .net framework, I think is resolved on the version 18 telegram bot, but the version was made for .net core , when send a message can add an option with the topic thread Id

Comment: which framework do you use? @MostafaBagheri?

Comment: did you solve your problem? And which PL do you use?

Comment: I Use .netframework 4.5.7 and my problem hasn't been solved yet.

Comment: @MostafaBagheri read this https://telegrambots.github.io/book/2/send-msg/text-msg.html, you can add threadId property in options to send message to specific thread.